# Excel: Can I control the allowed/default value of a cell based on a drop down list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Normally, I love using drop down lists to pre-populate document fields at work but I've run into an unusual (for me) situation where I basically need to use an "Other" field. I'm setting up an analysis spreadsheet where I am setting the type of data with a drop down list. Based on the data type, I want to allow different input conditions, i.e.:

```
Type   |   Input 1  |  Input 2
 A     |   Any num  |  Any num
 B     |   Any num  |  no value needed
 C     |   Any num  |  automatically populated
```

I'm familiar with using Data validation to control allowable inputs in a cell between set numbers or text but not if it can be used to sometimes allow anything and sometimes autopopulate a cell value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than preventing the user from entering invalid input using Data Validation, you could instead use Conditional Formatting to flash a big obvious warning on the errant cells.

For instance, if Type A is selected and Input 2 doesn't contain a number, have red highlighting on the Input 2 cell and also a warning message somewhere prominent. (Offhand, selectively-visible warning messages via conditional formatting can be done by manipulating number formatting or font colour.)

Combining user input and automatic data in one column means the user is overwriting formulas. I'd prefer to use an extra column which looks at user input or formulas for its value based on the Type selection:

```
Type  |  Input 1  |  Input 2     |  Corrected Input 2
 A    |  Any num  |  Any num     |  Lookup Input 2
 B    |  Any num  |  not needed  |  Lookup Input 2(?)
 C    |  Any num  |  <ignored>   |  Calculate from formula
```

(It's not clear in your question if Type B's Input 2 is optional or irrelevant. No matter.)

Comment: I considered conditional formatting and, if needed, will go that route but I am trying to automate as much as possible as this form is being used to support a group with a range of experiences. In the past, we've been burned by senior staff who were sure they "knew" the right answer and junior staff who (legitimately) didn't know better. I'm also looking at some macros to do this for me, maybe one that fires when you change the selection in the type column as a drop down list. ..... In A & B I don't control what is placed in the Input 2 column but, worst case, I  think your solution works. :)